# Android: ImageView display fail with big size

Tags: android, imageview

I have a problem with `ImageView` as below:
I have an image with big size (bigger than its part in screen), when I set src for `imageView` as:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_second_iv_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/phone_white"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/middle"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
```

then I put it into a `RelativeLayout`, problem is the content of image is displayed as wrap in the `ImageView` but size of `ImageView` is very big (seems as it auto create padding in the image view in four sides of `ImageView`, since my calculation for layout fails (can not align property position of child)).

Anybody can tell me what's the problem in here and how do I resolve this problem?

Please have a look at the image to have a better understanding. Also I added attribute:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

I can align the content as I want but size of ImageView still very big.

[image]

The xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:id="@+id/splash_slide_forth">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/splash_forth_tv_title"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/splash_4th_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textColor="#2b333b"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/splash_forth_tv_title"
    android:id="@+id/splash_forth_tv_desc"
    android:paddingLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingRight="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/splash_4th_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#2b333b"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />


<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@id/splash_forth_tv_desc"
    android:id="@+id/splash_forth_iv_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/phone_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@id/splash_forth_tv_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/splash_forth_iv_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/horizontal_phone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
```

Comment: Please show your whole XML with RelativeLayout

Comment: You don't need adjustViewBounds when using fitEnd.  The reason the entire ImageView is so big is because you're setting the "layout_below" parameter with "alignParentBottom". The RelativeLayout fills in the space between by resizing the ImageView. This shouldn't be an issue though. It's actually what you want in case as the screen gets smaller (although you may want to do a different layout when it's too small). Given the code you've provided I don't see why this is centering in the ImageView.

Comment: @DeeV: Could you tell me how can I fix my problem ?

Comment: @PhanDinhThai: How big is the image?  What folder are you putting the image in to?  I used a wallpaper image of 1980x1260 and ran code similar to yours and it scaled correctly with just fitEnd.

Comment: I put image into drawable folder. Can you show me your code @DeeV?

Comment: It's not much.  All I did was set the `layout_below="@+id/textview",  `alignParentBottom="true"` and `scaleType="fitEnd"`.  I recommend probably restarting the entire View with just the ImageView.  Make sure it scales correctly, then put in the other elements.

Answer (score -1):

Please set image as background,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_forth_iv_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/splash_forth_tv_desc"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:background="@drawable/demo_image"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

I really wish it works for you,otherwise we will do something else.

Comment: I tried and Image was scale as using scaleType = fitXY and size still very big :(

Comment: thanks, please keep in mind that the image has big size

Comment: Can you please add the image in your post.

Comment: I have copy your image, now you can remove it.
so that image you need to show on whole screen just below on those textviews?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81314/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-phan-dinh-thai).